# How can I issue one Insert statement for multiple rows in Propel

Tags: symfony, propel

is there a way to issue one INSERT statement instead of calling save() method on each object? Can I call save() on PropelObjectCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call save on a PropelObjectCollection from the class itself but it will issue multiple insert statements to do the work.

There is not much of a performance gain from issuing one INSERT rather than multiple if they are all wrapped in a transaction which Propel does by default. Also given the way Propel recurses to save related objects I suspect trying to do this would add a lot of complexity.

```
<?php

/**
 * This file is part of the Propel package.
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 *
 * @license    MIT License
 */

/**
 * Class for iterating over a list of Propel objects
 *
 * @author     Francois Zaninotto
 * @package    propel.runtime.collection
 */
class PropelObjectCollection extends PropelCollection
{
    /**
     * Save all the elements in the collection
     *
     * @param PropelPDO $con
     *
     * @throws PropelException
     */
    public function save($con = null)
    {
        if (!method_exists($this->getModel(), 'save')) {
            throw new PropelException('Cannot save objects on a read-only model');
        }
        if (null === $con) {
            $con = $this->getConnection(Propel::CONNECTION_WRITE);
        }
        $con->beginTransaction();
        try {
            /** @var $element BaseObject */
            foreach ($this as $element) {
                $element->save($con);
            }
            $con->commit();
        } catch (PropelException $e) {
            $con->rollback();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to put all of your save() calls in one transaction. In my code I had to insert 270 records in MySQL database.

Results without transactions:
real    0m15.127s
user    0m0.300s
sys 0m0.056s

Results with transactions:
real    0m0.687s
user    0m0.244s
sys 0m0.036s

There is a huge difference.